# Can display templates be uploaded to a subsite?

Tags: 2013, search, display-template

I have a client who only has access to their sub site, no root site collection access. They would like to be able to create a custom search page in their sub site and use a custom display template. Is there a way to upload a display template to a library in the sub site and have it be used by a content by search web part in that subsite?

Answer (score 1):

Unforunately not, display templates can only be uploaded to the masterpage gallery wich is located in the site collection, so you need to upload both display templates into the masterpage gallery.